# matplotlib: legend issue while embedding fonts in eps figure

Tags: fonts, matplotlib, legend

I create a plot and I select the font type to be TrueType (by using rcParams['ps.fonttype'] = 42).
I am using this image later on in a tex file and when I am creating the pdf file I check for the font types and I see
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
[none]                               Type 3            yes no no     160  0

But if I comment the legend while making the plot then I do not get a Type 3 font.

Why is that? It seems that the fonttype does not apply to the legend (or am I missing something?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After stepping on a similar post [[1](http://nerdjusttyped.blogspot.gr/2010/07/type-1-fonts-and-matplotlib-figures.html)] I found that the use of

rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

was enough to give me a final result with a Type 1 font!

[Note: dvipng has to be installed before adding these lines - or else matplotlib will complain and it will show you nothing]